# Computer random shutdown while playing game, 3 long beeps

Tags: hardware-failure

My computer randomly shutdown while playing a game.

It started beeping. 3 long beeps, 1 per second, then repeated after 5 seconds.

I just installed a new [GFX card (750 Ti)](http://www.mightyape.co.nz/product/Asus-GTX-750-Ti-DirectCU-II-OC-2GB-GDDR5-Graphics-Card/22290174), and reseated the CPU heat sink.

How do I diagnose the problem?

Answer (score 3):

3 long beeps is *normally* a memory issue but you don't mention what BIOS you have.

Since you've installed hardware, ensure the RAM is seated well.

Try with just 1 stick of RAM, and then swap it to see when/if the beep continues/stops. Then maybe use MEMTEST...

Read more about beep codes http://www.computerhope.com/beep.htm

However, I would first ensure everything is seated. It could be the new GPU isn't seated correctly...

Based upon now knowing your BIOS in the comments, here is the same question on a forum which also suggests it's faulty RAM 
https://communities.intel.com/thread/4817

Comment: I will run MEMTEST. How do I make sure there is enough power? The installed GFX card was a GeForce 750 Ti (upgraded from a GeForce 250), which did require a power input.

Comment: The power requirements are different for every GPU look your up then compare to your PSU

Comment: My PC boots up fine, its only under load it crashes, so will changing out RAM effect this?

Comment: Maybe the issue is when you're using the load it's more likely using corrupted memory. You are only making this change to test it all :) So yes, you'll need to strain the machine as you have been I would guess

Comment: This is the GFX card BTW, http://www.mightyape.co.nz/product/Asus-GTX-750-Ti-DirectCU-II-OC-2GB-GDDR5-Graphics-Card/22290174 I will try and update the question with the PSU etc.

Comment: What is the BIOS? What is the make/model of the computer

Comment: @DaveRook I think `wbibx10j` if that means anything

Comment: I don't think the PSU is the issue, I just mention it could be...

Comment: @Petah I updated my question with a link - I think this proves the issue

Comment: Alright Im running memtest now, should the confirm the issue?

Comment: @Petah - You need to do multiple passes.  It should not fail a single pass.  Good memory will contain zero errors ( this is because the error correction that exists).  So if you have detectable error it means you have more errors then the error correction can resolve.

Comment: It failed on the first pass, what now?

Comment: What don't you understand? The RAM (a stick or multiple sticks) are faulty. Bin it. Buy new.